# Flattening folders programmatically

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command-line, directory

I have a folder which contains a set of directories.

I want to iterate over all directories in this root folder and, if these contain folders, flatten them (i.e put them all into the original directory, unless the folder is named "exception".

So I have

```
>Root Folder
   >directory
     >subdirectory
      file1
     >subdirectory2
      file2
   >directory2
     >exception
      file3
   >directory3
     >subdirectory3
      file4
```

to change to (blank line indicates where subdirectory has been deleted) :

> Root Folder
>   directory

```
     file1

     file2
   >directory2
     >exception
      file3
   >directory3

     file4
```

Each sub-directory could contain n other subdirectories so a recursive solution I think would be best here, something like :

```
for each directory d in root folder
   find every file/folder in d not isCalled("exception")
   copy all files into directory d
   delete all folders in directory d
```

I'm unsure what technologies would facilitate doing this in windows, however, could anyone help? How can I write a script to do this most simply? I've googled at length with no definitive answers so any help is most appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for is windows batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is windows batch.

Solution (not tested):

#### Main.bat

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  Clear "%%~a" 
  rmdir %%a
)
```

#### Clear.bat

```
@echo off
set root=C:\Path\To\Root\
:: Edit above line. Make sure you include last "\"
cd %1
move * %root%
for /d %%d in (*) do (
  if "%%d" NEQ "exemption" (
    %root%clear "%%~d"
    rmdir %%d
  )
)
```

And that should work. Put both files in the root directory. If there is a bug in the `clear` batch file it should be safe as `rmdir` wont clean empty directories.

Comment: many thanks for the response, when I run this it error message however :
Clear "123"
rmdir 123
)
'Clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the file specified. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @SimonKiely Are clear.bat and main.bat both in the root directory. Are they both named exactly that